# Showing user and userinterface interaction on a sequence diagram

Tags: uml, modeling, sequence-diagram

I need to draw a sequence diagram and I am not sure exactly if it is correct to show interaction between user and user interface in this diagram. For example I want to make a panel visible or invisible based on choosing a check box by user. Is it correct to have it on a sequence diagram? and how can I draw it?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UML allows to you to place an actor in a sequence diagram. The actor ("user") has a lifeline like any object instance. I'd say that "checking the check box" is the message, that the user sends to your check box instance. Alternatively you can take the [IBM approach](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/3101.html) and let the initial event be an incoming message to your first instance.

Comment: Do you suggest that I put a check box instance on the diagram or a UI instance I mean a form instance. which one is more appropriate? If I put a check box instance so I have to show every control on the diagram.

Comment: The check box is very detailed. If you need this information it is okay. Usually I'd prefer the containing form/dialog. Suppose you change the check box to a radio button or a combo box or something else. If you do so, the diagram with the check box will be out of date.